# Length of longest street using Spatial SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, linestring, length

I have a table with the geometry of streets and I`d like to find out, which is the longest and which length (in kilometers) it is.

How can I summarize the individual street segments?

Comment: What do you mean by "individual street segments"? You are already grouping by geometry in addition to the "ref" attribute. The geometry is almost (but not completely) guaranteed to be unique already so you are probably effectively making no groups at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understanding grouping in SQL is essential in everyday DB usage, and it has the potential to get diabolically complicated to manage across complex queries if unfamiliar.

At the core, a `GROUP BY` statement will uniquely categorize rows across the given distinct column(s) values; same values go into the same category, with their respective rows being collected. And given two columns, as in your example, it will categorize hierarchically; find groups within each group.

In your case, PostgreSQL will first group all values of `geom` into categories (likely, each geometry is different, so you'll end up with as many groups as there are geometries), then tries to find unique values for `ref` within each of those groups of rows (again, in your case, since there is likely only one row per group, nothing changes).

Instead, you want to only collect (`GROUP BY`) all rows that have the same `ref`, and aggregate (`SUM`) the length of their geometries:

```
SELECT ref,
       SUM(ST_Length(geom) / 1000) AS km
FROM   <table_expression>
GROUP BY
       ref
;
```

---

Note that `ST_Length` will return values in the units of the underlying CRS, so it will be *degrees* for geodetic reference systems! You seem to have a projection in place that returns *meter*; if that wasn't the case, using PostGIS `GEOGRAPHY` type on a geodetic reference system would yield high precision results in *meter*, i.e.

```
SELECT ref,
       SUM(ST_Length(geom::GEOGRAPHY) / 1000) AS km
FROM   <table_expression>
GROUP BY
       ref
;
```